# rh-php70-php-cli-7.0.27-1.el7.x86_64 installed but not works

Tags: php

```
[root@du ~]# yum install rh-php70-php-cli.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.dhakacom.com
 * extras: mirror.dhakacom.com
 * updates: mirror.dhakacom.com
Package rh-php70-php-cli-7.0.27-1.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

[root@du Web]# php test.php 
bash: php: command not found...
```

I have installed `rh-php70-php-cli-7.0.27-1.el7.x86_64` for my CentOS 7 web server. And I connect the server with ssh and run these above command.

I also installed `rh-php70-php-pdo-7.0.27-1.el7.x86_64` which doesn't work.

Can you guess the problem?

Comment: Why do you think the command is "php"?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams then what is the command? In my previous time I use `php` in my local machine and also server before reconfiguration my server.

Comment: You supposedly have access to the machine. Ask the package manager.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I have access the machine. I have to do all things for the server. One officer give me the address, permission and he refuses to give time for that machine.

Answer (score 0):

The author might have found it by now, but for other just in case : the package description at [pkgs.org](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-sclo-rh-x86_64/rh-php70-php-cli-7.0.27-2.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) in files section indicate that binaries are in

> /opt/rh/rh-php70/root/usr/bin/

You should, I think, just add this to your $PATH env variable, or use the absolute path.